# How to select specific data from 3 tables? [PostgreSQL 9.1]

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, postgresql-9.1

```
# select * from users ;
 user_id | login  |          email          | password | firstname | lastname 
---------+--------+-------------------------+----------+-----------+----------
       1 | katie  | katie.s@ymail.com       | secret   | Katie     | Secret
(1 row)

# select * from forum;
 forum_id | forum_name | group_id | forum_parent 
----------+------------+----------+--------------
         1|  1st forum |        1 |            -1
(1 row)

# select * from groups;
 group_id |      group_name       |                group_description                | group_founder 
----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------
        1 | Java programming      | System.out.println("Hello world in Java!"); :)  |             1
(1 row)
```

I have those 3 tables in my database. I would like to get from it forums which are created by user with `id = 1`. How to do this? (in table `groups`, `id` of the user which created such group is called `group_founder`).

I mean, with the output above, you can see that user with `id = 1` created a group "Java programming" and then created within this group a forum, called "1st forum". Please, help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM forum f
JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = f.group_id
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = g.group_founder 
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your inputs, the query may be that way

```
SELECT U.login,U.email,U.firstname
FROM users U JOIN groups G ON U.user_id = G.group_founder
             JOIN forum F ON G.group_id = F.group_id
WHERE U.user_id = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbd85/2)

Comment: @Katie - pleased to help :)